# Facebook request dialog

Tags: facebook, dialog

I am using FB.ui to enable the user to send requests and I provide a default message.

```
FB.ui({
        method: 'apprequests',
        message: 'You should learn more about this awesome game.'},

);
```

Is it possible, in a *Facebook request dialog*, for the user to write his/her own message ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not in the UI for the requests dialog, but you can build a textarea into your own UI, which populates the `message` field in your `FB.ui` call.

Comment: How can I build the textarea inside the UI

Comment: You can't build inside the Facebook UI, but what I'm suggesting is that you have your own UI with an area for users to input a message, then you pass the contents of that `textarea` to your `FB.ui` call.